# Alert reviewers when a tag wiki has already gotten reject votes for plagarism

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-wiki, plagiarism

After episodes like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183715/tag-edit-plagiarist-spammer), I think it would be good if we added a new feature to the tag wiki review page. If a user clicks Approve after the edit has already revived a "Copied Content" rejection, show a warning message and a confirmation before the user is allowed to approve. I think this would help our plagiarism problem with tag wikis.